# Row counts Sql query

Tags: html, sql-query-store

I want result in Sql query

```
id1     id2     id3     Count Id
A001    A001    A001    3
A001    NULL    A001    2
A001    NULL    NULL    1
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, i would use `VALUES` construct  :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(tt.ids) FROM ( VALUES (t.id1), (t.id2), (t.id3) ) tt(ids)
       ) as Count_Id
FROM table t;
```

In standard SQL you can use `CASE` Expression :

```
SELECT t.*,
       ( (CASE WHEN ID1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         (CASE WHEN ID2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         (CASE WHEN ID3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       ) AS Count_Id
FROM table t
```

Comment: [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jqHPWJ7PiokCVJ7uMphmrx/0) to demonstrate standard SQL answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you find something like below

```
 select id1,id2,id3, 
case when id1 is not null then 1  else 0 end+ 
case when id2 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
case when id3 is not null then 1 else 0 end as val
```